# Can't convert systems.collections.generic.list<systems.collections.generic.list<string>> to string

Tags: c#

Not sure why this isn't working, but I have:

```
public static string SetRows(DataTable table, int maximumCount)
{
    var finalFile = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        int i = 0;
        List<string> excelTotal = new List<string>();
        for (i = 0; i < maximumCount; i++)
        {
            excelTotal.Add(row[i].ToString());                   
        }
        finalFile.Add(excelTotal);
    }

    return finalFile;
}
```

I'm creating a list inside another list.

Comment: Your return types are mismatched. What about the error don't you understand?

Comment: You are returning a List, yet your method declaration says it returns a string

Answer (score 5):

The return type of the method is `string`. It should be `List<List<string>>` as this is what the method is returning.

Change the method declaration to be:

```
public static List<List<string>> SetRows(DataTable table, int maximumCount)
```